# How to use Jackson annotations( or any other way)to get a complex data in the deserialization?

Tags: java, json, hibernate, orm, jackson

I use Entity Models with json serialization/deserialization to store/retrieve data .
I face issue to deserialize Lazy loaded data.

That is, I have defined my entity,superclass, interface like this;

**ATG Class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "atg", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "code"))
public class ATG extends ParentEntity {

    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "companyid")
    Manufacturer manufacturer;

    getManufacturer();
    setManufacturer();    
}
```

**Customer class**

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public class Customer implements HasCustomer {

    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer2_id", nullable = true)
    private Customer customer;

    getCustomer();
    setCustomer();
}
```

**ParentEntity**

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class ParentEntity implements  HasCustomer{

    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
    @ManyToOne( fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer2_id", nullable = false)
    private Customer customer;

    getCustomer();
    setCustomer();
}
```

**HasCustomer Interface**

```
public interface HasCustomer extends Serializable{

    public Customer getCustomer();

    public void setCustomer(final Customer customer);

    public Long getCustomerId();

    public void setCustomerId(final Long customerId);
}
```

Customer Class has a reference to customer object(logical requirement).

I make REST calls to my service endpoints to retrieve data from the database. Ide fined those complex dataTypes as fetch = FetchType.LAZY.
When user really requires those data with the response , he will specify. So, at the backend we  fetch data by setting FetchMode.JOIN. (This works).

Only problem is, Json annotations. How should i specify annotations in this case? 
If I keep jsonIgnore at one level, it may block results or I see results all the time when user is not requested to fetch the complex  data

I tried `@jsonIgnore` /`@jsonproperty` annotations on all getters, setters and the in the variable definition. (I believe I tried all combinations :)

But none is returning the desired results.

I want to keep proper annotation to retrieve **customer data and manufacturer data when making calls to ATG service**

Can anybody help me out?

I use jackson(com.fasterxml.jackson) V 2.6.3 hibernate v 5.2.1.Final.

Comment: What is "desired result"? It is not 100% obvious so you may want to specify it, either as JSON or explaining like "Should not have property 'customer'".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you should be using Jackson like this, but this may help.

Define a customer serializer

```
public class CustomerSerializer extends JsonDeserializer<Customer> {

   public Customer deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        ....
    }
}
```

Then use it in your interface

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = CustomerSerializer.class)
public class Customer implements HasCustomer {
```

Comment: This solution gives ' customer 'everytime. It looks my customJsondeserilizer class is not called at all.